# Checkbox Won't Stay In CheckBox (Android)

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a `CheckedTextView`, and whenever I click on the check area, the check goes away as soon as I lift my finger. I have my `ListView` set to `ChoiceMultiple`, so I don't know what the problem is.

Here's my source if necessary: [Source Code](https://github.com/cg2916/ShoppingList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't forget to call `setItemsCanFocus(true)` on your ListView. This enables ListView items to get focus.

Secondly, your `rowlayout.xml` contains a `CheckedTextView` inside a `RelativeLayout`. In this case, `CheckedTextView` cannot get focus because of its parent `RelativeLayout`.

So, remove its parent `RelativeLayout` and keep only the `CheckedTextView`.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkedtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

Comment: It worked!!! Now I just have to figure out how to delete all items from the SQLite